# How to infer the correct generic type in this case?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
type secondaryObjectConstraint = {
    [key: string]: number
}

abstract class Base<TObject extends object, TSecondaryObject extends secondaryObjectConstraint> {}


type secondaryObjectType = {
    myProp: number
}

class ExtendedObject extends Base<{}, secondaryObjectType> {}

type inferSecondaryObject<M extends Base<any, any>> = M extends Base<any, infer TSecondaryObject> ? TSecondaryObject : never;

const a: inferSecondaryObject<ExtendedObject> = {};
```

In the above example, `a` gets the type of `secondaryObjectConstraint`, instead of the more exact `secondaryObjectType`. What am I doing wrong here? How could I infer the `secondaryObjectType` in my above example?

Link to [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAzhDGB7AdgEwIYCcQHkBGAVgsAMIozCboCWywUAvFAN4BQUHUA2gNYQgAuWJVoBzALpDkAVwC2eCJlYBfVq3R4KVePXgAbdDBhQAQoYgAeACr4iOqBAAewCGmOJCxADRQrAZQQUDGxbYgdnV1RjOCQ0LFxPHTJkLRo6AD4WVTVQSFhAuJDE4CtwaCY2TihZEAAFTEQwKTkFJWz9Q2MAUQi0CFRQ%20ycXN1NzC2ZlHxig%20MGSsszJnLKoWgAzRQDY4IS7YAsAWXCRqLG4C3RkEB8rkHTMpmPhyOMzC7ufDcVfbdmi-aZAD8vwKu3mUCkEAAbooANxqWIUKDoITfTB-Qp7YgWHqnfrzR5ZOFQAD0pKgAHcABYgKCoRAQYzAanUYyiCDAYzozD9KDARD5HZzYrJVK0ei0CgQdCoKCIdZC-7YnSlPJAoA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--) for an authoritative answer.

TypeScript's type system is largely [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) and not [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system).  If two types `A` and `B` have the same *structure* (e.g., both of them have the same property names of the same property types), then TypeScript considers them to be the same type.  The compiler is free to treat `A` and `B` completely interchangeably. This is true even if `A` and `B` have different *names* or *declaration sites*.

Let's look at your `Base` class:

```
abstract class Base<
  TObject extends object, 
  TSecondaryObject extends SecondaryObjectConstraint
> { }
```

The structure of that class is... [empty](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-oop.html#empty-types).  An instance of `Base<X, Y>` has no known properties at all.  And therefore, by structural typing, it is identical to the empty object type `{}`.  It has no structural dependency on the `TObject` or `TSecondaryObject` type parameters.

This also implies that `Base<{}, SecondaryObjectType>` and `Base<object, SecondaryObjectConstraint>` are structurally identical to each other, and the compiler is free to treat them interchangeably.  Thus, *all bets are off* when it comes to trying to infer `X` and `Y` from the type `Base<X, Y>`.  All you know is that you'll get some types consistent with their [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).

It's *possible* that the compiler will be able to return `Y` from `Base<X, Y> extends Base<X, infer T> ? T : never`, but there's no guarantee.  And unfortunately, with your intermediate `ExtendedObject` class, you end up with the constraint type instead of the specific type you were hoping for.

---

If you want more of a guarantee, you should make sure that your types have a structural dependence on the types you care about.  Generic types should always use their type parameters in some structural way.  For example:

```
abstract class Base<T extends object, U extends SecondaryObjectConstraint> {
    t!: T;
    u!: U
}
```

So a `Base<T, U>` has a `t` property of type `T` and a `u` property of type `U`.  And now you get the desired behavior:

```
type IOEO = InferSecondaryObject<ExtendedObject>;
/* type IOEO = {
    myProp: number;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhDGB7AdgEwIYCcQHkBGAVgsAMIoDOwm6AlssFALxQDeAUFJ1ANoDWEIAFxRKmOgHMAusOQBXALZ4ImNgF82bdHlHp4DeABt05clABCxiAB4AKlAgAPYBDSnEhYgBooAVXtOXVFM4JDQsXA89MmQdOmAAPlYOLmAAQmEbAG5kzll03zUNUEhYBBQMbHwiPRtwaGZ2Lih5EAAFTEQwGQUlFXU2Q2NTAFEAtAhUKuJ-Z1dzSysWVW8Q8vCpmrrElih+4ugASWQAM2VVsMrI4CsAWRnA0wtya3RkEG9XkHjExhyoO8csyC82eVk+3jop0wUBs5wqEWqCSgAH4YXD1lcoDIIAA3ZTZNj7KAHHDDHBMYknM5lC4I4hWUZAiYbBLZAD0ACooESSWSKY0uC12p1uop8WooBy2WwgA)

Comment: If using the above approach, are there any drawbacks to instead of infering the type, accessing it directly, with: `type IOEO = ExtendedObject['u'];` ?

Comment: I'd say `ExtendedObject['u']` is preferable to using `infer`, since the compiler can often reason better about indexed accesses than about conditional type inference.  But the `infer` method is more general and doesn't depend on the exact nature of the structural dependence.